# How to detach nodes and edge part of a tidygraph tibble into two separate pure tibbles

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidygraph

I have the following [tidygraph tibble](https://github.com/thomasp85/tidygraph):

```
rstat_nodes <- data.frame(name = c("Hadley", "David", "Romain", "Julia"), sex = c("M","M","M","F"))
rstat_edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), 
                            to = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3))
g <- tbl_graph(nodes = rstat_nodes, edges = rstat_edges)
g
```

It looks like this:

```
> g
# A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 9 edges
#
# A directed simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 4 x 2 (active)
  name   sex  
  <fct>  <fct>
1 Hadley M    
2 David  M    
3 Romain M    
4 Julia  F    
#
# Edge Data: 9 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     1     4
# … with 6 more rows
```

Is there a convenient way to split them into [two pure tibbles](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/) one for 
node part another for edge part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am relatively new to tidygraphs.. Interesting to see what the data structure is like, but maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
# to get nodes
g %>% activate(nodes) %>% as_tibble()
# to get edges
g %>% activate(nodes) %>% as_tibble()
```